# javascript function doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi,I have simple login form, where fields are validated by javascript.
 I don't now why the below code is not working.

**my html and js code:**

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleLogin() {

            var u = $("#username").val();
            var p = $("#password").val();

            if(u=="a" && p=="a")
                {

                window.location="/Site/site.html";
                }
            else
                {
                alert("Fail");
                }

        }
        </script>

</head> 
<li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem"> 
            <input dojoType="dojox.mobile.app.TextBox" placeHolder="username" type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        </li>
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem">
            <input dojoType="dojox.mobile.app.TextBox" placeHolder="password" type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        </li>
        <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.ListItem">
            <input dojoType="dojox.mobile.Button" onclick="handleLogin()" type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/> 
        </li>
```

When I click on the submit button nothings happening.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error in firebug console ?

Comment: Did you actually load jQuery?

Comment: do you get any error ? Are you sure the function isn't executed ?

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EnkrT/

Comment: I didn't get any errors.

Comment: Do you have more code?  It executes fine for me without any changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't load the jQuery library. But you can do without it:

```
var u = document.getElementById('username').value,
p = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Changing the page is done with `location.href` instead of `window.location`:

```
location.href = '/Site/site.html';
```

Comment: I don't want load jQuery and I forgot when I wrote this. This solution without jQuery doesn't work

Comment: @user1031034 Oh, I've corrected a typo; that was probably it.

Comment: @dreamweiver `Node.val()` is not a function in pure JS and `getElementById()` doesn't take a selector.

Comment: Now it's work :) but only when I have incorrect data in form. But when I have corect it's do nothing. It's good redirect to other site in javascript (without jquery). `window.location="/Site/site.html";`

Comment: @Jack: Thanks for the correction jack, typical mistake when you are addicted to jQuery lib :)

Comment: @user1031034: If you have found the answer then tick it against the right answer, this would reduce the no of open questions.

Comment: @user1031034 You should probably use `location.href` instead of `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

try to import

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```